# Get a cell value from excel using EPPlus and Linq

Tags: c#, linq, epplus

Is it possible to get a cell value from excel sheet using EPPlus and Linq?
Example:

I have an excel sheet with 3 columns

```
Column 1 = Userid
Column 2 = Email address
Column 3 = Full name
```

Now i would like to return the **email address** where **userid = x**

I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I'm not clear about your doubt. Please explain more. To make any query, we need to open the package first, like open a connection in Linq to SQL.

Comment: Edited, my question is much more simple than that, i just want to know how to do simple (select,from, where ) operation using EPPlus and Linq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose `Column 1` is `a`, `Column 2` is `b`:

```
var sheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[sheetname_orSheetIndex];
var objs = from cell in sheet.Cells["a:a"]        // a:a is the column a, Userid
           where cell.Value.ToString().Equals(x)  // x is the input userid
           select sheet.Cells[cell.Start.Row, 2]; // 2 is column b, Email Address
```

It will work!
Edited: It will return the collection of ExcelRange.

Answer (score 3):

Not being exactly sure what you are trying to do, here is an example of getting the value from a cell:

```
  excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets
                .FirstOrDefault(w => w.Name == "Your Worksheet Name")
                .Cells.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Address == "Your Cell Address").Value;
```

Just make sure you are using the System.Linq namespace

Comment: If you know the exact sheet and cell address why do you use Linq to make everything complex. Furthermore, `FirstOrDefault` can return `null` so please be careful when try to access any property.

Comment: I know the sheet name but i don't know the cell address. please re-check my question after i have edited it.