# Error Showing "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine." in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, excel-2010

I am using `Windows 7 64bit`, but am getting this Error:

> "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine."

My Code for creating a connection looks like this:

```
var fileName = @"C:\ExcelFile.xlsx";
var connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
using (var conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();

    var sheets = conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" });
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheets.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString() + "] ";

        var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        var ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);
    }
}
```

How can i resolve this problem in a 64bit Application?

In my projects settings i used the setting `Any CPU` for the application.

Comment: Have you installed the access database engine?

Comment: Taking a dependency on ACE in a 64-bit program is just plain unwise.  Microsoft doesn't want to support it, doesn't provide an installer and it takes installing something else with just the right kind of secret incantations to get it to work.  Use OpenXML instead.

Comment: There are plenty of duplicates here for this particular question, please go through at least a few of them to see if any of the solutions work. In particular check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26097143/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-e - which supports @HansPassant comment.

Comment: You can use the Open XML SDK to open the file or a library like EPPlus. EPPlus allows you to use LINQ to query the data. Check [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13857559/get-a-cell-value-from-excel-using-epplus-and-linq)

Comment: yes, am also getting same error how can i solve this

Comment: in 64 bit it will not work

Answer (score 0):

Need to install `Access Database Engine`. Download it from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Note: It will need to be installed on every machine running your application, so you should make it a part of Prerequisites in the Publish settings.

Comment: Are you install 64 bit version of `Access Database Engine`?

Answer (score -1):

I have a solution that is not perfect, but it works, the idea is to convert your XLSX file into a csv file, and read it as a CSV file, the advantage here that you don't have to install the provider on each machine. (in my example I backed up the contents of my file in DATATABLE ), I also used the SpreadsheetControl (you need to add the reference)
here is the code,

```
     var fileName = @"C:\ExcelFile.xlsx";

 SpreadsheetControl spreadsheetControl1 = new SpreadsheetControl();

 using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
 {
     spreadsheetControl1.LoadDocument(stream, DocumentFormat.OpenXml);
 }
 IWorkbook workbook = spreadsheetControl1.Document;
 workbook.Options.Export.Csv.ValueSeparator = ';';
 workbook.SaveDocument("d:\\test.csv", DocumentFormat.Csv);
 string whole_file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(FileName);

 // Split into lines.
 whole_file = whole_file.Replace('\n', '\r');
 string[] lines = whole_file.Split(new char[] { '\r' },
     StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

 // See how many rows and columns there are.
 int num_rows = lines.Length;
 int num_cols = lines[0].Split(',').Length;

 // Allocate the data array.
 string[,] values = new string[num_rows, num_cols];

 // Load the array.
 for (int r = 0; r < num_rows; r++)
 {
     string[] line_r = lines[r].Split(',');
     for (int c = 0; c < num_cols; c++)
         values[r, c] = line_r[c];
         //MessageBox.Show(line_r[c]);
 }

 int end;
 for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
 {

     int itemcount = values[i, 0].Count(x => x == ';');
     string tmpch = values[i, 0];
     string valeuradd;

     if (i == 0)
     {
         for (int x = 1; x < itemcount + 2; x++)
         {
             end = tmpch.IndexOf(";");
             if (end <= 0) { end = tmpch.Length; }
             valeuradd = tmpch.Substring(0, end);                       
             tmpch = tmpch.Substring(end + 1);                       
             DT.Columns.Add(valeuradd);
         }
     }

     else
     {
         DataRow row;
         row = DT.NewRow();
         for (int j = 1; j < itemcount + 2; j++)
         {

             end = tmpch.IndexOf(";");
             //MessageBox.Show(j.ToString());
             if (end <= 0) { end = tmpch.Length; }
             valeuradd = tmpch.Substring(0, end);
             row[j - 1] = valeuradd;                       
           tmpch = tmpch.Substring(end + 1);                       
         }
         DT.Rows.Add(row);
     }
 }
```

File.Delete("d:\test.csv");

I know this can be complicated, but it works.

Comment: There's no reason at all to convert an Excel file to an incompatible CSV file, that will miss worksheets, won't be able treat special characters, mix up thousand separators etc. Besides, `xlsx` is a gzip compressed XML file, for which there is a well known SDK (Open XML SDK) and libraries that make working with it very easy

Comment: I mentioned that the solution I have just posted is not perfect, I only said that it works very well, and it does not need to install any provider, at the conversion of XLSX file into CSV the character of separation is given, so the program knows how to treat our CSV file.

Comment: Unless there is a thousand separator, or any kind of error or bug that results in lost data due to the `catch {}` expressions. And it does require an additional library or application, since there is no such thing as `SpreadsheetControl` in .Net.